# code igniter - form dropdown selecting correct value from database (state & city using javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, html, codeigniter

I have a similar problem like this one: [Code Igniter - form_dropdown selecting correct value from the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331078/code-igniter-form-dropdown-selecting-correct-value-from-the-database), but in this case, i have 2 dropdown, State & City (using JavaScript). The dropdown option for City is repopulated based on what user choose in State dropdown.

For example, when a user choose a State (eg: New York), then the dropdown options for City become only cities in New York (eg: Albany, Amsterdam etc).

After user selects a value, then hits save, its saved to the database.

The problem is, how do i get the dropdown to automatically choose the one thats been selected by the user in the initial stage? I can do it if it's only 1 dropdown option. But in this case, the dropdown for City is repopulated based on what user choosed in State dropdown option.

Controller:

```
//this one i managed to get it automatically choose the one that's been selected by the user in the initial stage    
$username=$this->session->userdata('username'); 
$data['orgtype'] = $this->m_user->get_orgtype_dropdown($username);

//these two are the problem 
$data['state'] = $this->m_user->get_state_dropdown($username); 
$data['city'] = $this->m_user->get_city_dropdown($username);
```

Model:

```
function get_orgtype_dropdown($username){
$sqlstr="SELECT * FROM a01 WHERE username='$username'";
$hslquery=$this->db->query($sqlstr);
   foreach($hslquery->result_array() as $row){
        $return[$row['orgtype']] = $row['orgtype'];
        }
    return $return;
}

function get_state_dropdown($username){
$sqlstr="SELECT * FROM a01 WHERE username='$username'";
$hslquery=$this->db->query($sqlstr);       
   foreach($hslquery->result_array() as $row){
        $return[$row['state']] = $row['state'];
        }
    return $return;
}

function get_city_dropdown($username){
$sqlstr="SELECT * FROM a01 WHERE username='$username'";
$hslquery=$this->db->query($sqlstr);       
   foreach($hslquery->result_array() as $row){
        $return[$row['city']] = $row['city'];
        }
    return $return;
}
```

View:

```
<?php
$orgtypeOption = array(
         'Academic'  => 'Academic',
         'Professional'    => 'Professional',                  
         );

    echo form_label("Organization Type : ");
    echo form_dropdown('orgtype', $orgtypeOption, $orgtype);
    echo br();
    echo form_label("State : ");            
    ?>
    <select name ="state" id="countrySelect" size="1" onChange="makeSubmenu(this.value)">
        <option></option>
        <option value="USA" <?php if ($state=="USA") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>USA</option>
        <option value="Singapore" <?php if ($state=="Singapore") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Singapore</option>
        <option value="Jawa Timur" <?php if ($state=="Jawa Timur") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Jawa Timur</option>
        <option value="Jawa Barat" <?php if ($state=="Jawa Barat") echo 'selected="selected"';?>>Jawa Barat</option>
    </select>
    <?php
    echo br();
    echo form_label("City : ");
    ?>
    <select name="city" id="citySelect" size="1">
        <option></option>
    </select>
```

JavaScript:

```
var citiesByState = {
    USA: ["NY","NJ"],
    Singapore: ["taas","naas"],
    "Jawa Timur": ["Surabaya","Malang"],
    "Jawa Barat": ["Bandung","Banjar"]
};
function makeSubmenu(value) {
    if(value.length==0) document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
    else {
        var citiesOptions = "";
        for(cityId in citiesByState[value]) {
            citiesOptions+="<option>"+citiesByState[value][cityId]+"</option>";
        }
        document.getElementById("citySelect").innerHTML = citiesOptions;
    }
}
function displaySelected() {
    var country = document.getElementById("countrySelect").value;
    var city = document.getElementById("citySelect").value;
    alert(country+"\n"+city);
}
function resetSelection() {
    document.getElementById("countrySelect").selectedIndex = 0;
    document.getElementById("citySelect").selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Here's the preview: [application preview picture](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-Dr8yklo_fKQ/UWdngNtyqoI/AAAAAAAAAG4/XyRqhM9EYws/s549/Dropdown.jpg)

Help please

Comment: Do you try using `AJAX`?